# Set comparator with variables within a variable, then have shell expand those variables each time it's echo'd

Tags: shell-script, shell, posix

Here's part of my script:

```
#!/bin/sh

n=1

echo "How many repetitions to run (0 = no limit)?"
read reps

if [ $reps = 0 ]; then
    while="true"
else
    while="[ $n -lt $((reps+1)) ]"
fi

echo "How much off-time in-between reps (in minutes)?"
read time

pwr_init

while $while; do
    echo "* Sending power pulse $n"
    pwr_normal
    t=$time
    echo "* Waiting for next power on"
    while [ $t -gt 0 ]; do
        echo "    $t min until next power on"; sleep 60
        t=$((t-1))
    done
    n=$((n+1))
done
```

Everything is working exactly as I need it to, except for the first `while` loop I have going on. Whenever the `$while` variable is called, I'd like shell to expand and check the variables at that moment that are defined in the first `if` statement.

I can only get shell to expand the variables at the moment of the first `if` statement, but then I get the behavior like `true` because the comparator is always true and never changes when `$n` gets incremented, because that `$while` variable has already expanded everything during the first `if` statement.

I've tried methods like `${!while}` and various combinations of single and double quotes, but no luck. I usually get errors like `$n is a bad number` or `bad substitution`.

Right now the only thing I can think of is to add even more `if` statements within more functions to check and echo this line to the `while` statement every time. I have to believe there's a better way to do this, though, I'm just having a hard time figuring it out (and also finding the right keywords to search for online).

While debugging, I use `set -x`, and can see that the comparator string is being evaluated properly in the way the script is written here, but as I mentioned it never updates itself when `$n` is incremented.

Does anyone have a trick for this type of substitution that makes life just a little easier? Much appreciated any insight that can be given into this odd variable expansion conundrum!

NOTE1: `pwr_init` and `pwr_normal` are functions defined elsewhere in the full script.

NOTE2: Take note of the shebang, it must be POSIX compliant. I can't use any fancy bash specific techniques.

EDIT: Getting this to function like I need was less convoluted than I thought, and I'm putting what I added below. However, I'm leaving the question open as it would be great to know whether or not this type of variable expansion can be done.

New script with the `check` function wrapped around the `if` statement:

```
#!/bin/sh

n=1

echo "How many repetitions to run (0 = no limit)?"
read reps

count=$((reps+1))

check() {
    if [ $reps = 0 ]; then
        while="true"
    else
        while="[ $n -lt $count ]"
    fi
}

echo "How much off-time in-between reps (in minutes)?"
read time

pwr_init

while $while; do
    echo "* Sending power pulse $n"
    pwr_normal
    t=$time
    echo "* Waiting for next power on"
    while [ $t -gt 0 ]; do
        echo "    $t min until next power on"; sleep 60
        t=$((t-1))
    done
    n=$((n+1))
    check
done
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Extra simple solution:** to run an "without end", just set the limit to some insanely large number. A 32-bit integer can hold numbers up to 4294967296. Allowing for a sign bit, and rounding down, we could assume we can count up to at least 2000000000. Since you're sleeping for at least a minute between the counts, that works for up to, oh about 4000 years.

So just do:

```
if [ "$reps" = 0 ]; then
    reps=2000000000
fi
```

And hardwire the condition to be

```
while [ "$n" -le "$reps" ]; do ...
```

(If you're running a 64-bit system, you can count even higher. Not that it matters. If you're running a 16-bit system instead, then you're likely to be screwed in other ways too.)

---

**Simple solution:** Just make a function to check for if `reps` is zero or `n` is smaller than `reps`.

```
keep_going() {
    [ "$reps" = 0 ] && return 0
    [ "$n" -le "$reps" ] 
}
```

and then make the condition

```
while keep_going; do ...
```

Yes, you'll call a function each time. No, it doesn't matter, since you only do it once a minute at maximum. (And if you did care about being fast, you shouldn't use the shell to do it.)

---

**The solution you're looking for:** Use `eval`. With the double quotes in the assignment to `while="[ $n -lt $count ]"`, both `$n` and `$count` will be expanded immediately. What you need is to use single quotes in the assignment: `while='[ $n -lt $count ]'` and then run the string through `eval` to have the variables there expanded.

```
while='[ $n -lt $count ]'
while eval "$while" ; do ...
```

Comment: Both of the 1st options would definitely work, and I hadn't thought about just running another function like you suggested in the 2nd simple solution.

The final bit was exactly what I was looking for though, thank you! I saw some info out there about using eval, but I never could get it to work. What you put here does indeed expand like I expect, I must not have tried it exactly like that although I was using single quotes. Marked as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You might try defining different functions:

```
if [ $reps -eq 0 ]; then
    while_test() { true; }
else
    while_test() { test $1 -lt $((reps+1)); }
fi
```

then

```
while while_test $n; do
```

---

You can use `eval` in a POSIX shell to work with the condition in a variable:

```
$ cond='[ $n -lt $reps ]'
$ reps=5
$ n=4
$ eval "$cond" && echo 'n < reps' || echo 'n >= reps'
n < reps
$ n=5
$ eval "$cond" && echo 'n < reps' || echo 'n >= reps'
n >= reps
```

Make sure the condition is defined in single quotes so the variables are not expanded prematurely.

Comment: Good approach! This is a little cleaner than what I ended up implementing and would ultimately solve the issue I was having. Unfortunately, it doesn't answer the question of how to have the nested variables expand every time the main variable is expanded.